# Combining timeseries from two tables

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to combine two tables, each of which has the same data structure. I want to create a single table that incorporates the data from both tables as follows:

**Table 1** - timeFrom and timeTo are regularly spaced (new row every 30 minutes):

| periodFrom | periodTo | timeFrom | timeTo | levelFrom | levelTo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 00:00 | 00:30 | 50 | 50 |
| 2 | 2 | 00:30 | 01:00 | 50 | 50 |
| 3 | 3 | 01:00 | 01:30 | 50 | 50 |
| 4 | 4 | 01:30 | 02:00 | 50 | 50 |

**Table 2** - timeFrom and timeTo are irregularly spaced (more or less than 30 minutes):

| periodFrom | periodTo | timeFrom | timeTo | levelFrom | levelTo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 00:15 | 01:15 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 4 | 01:30 | 01:32 | 50 | 60 |
| 4 | 4 | 01:32 | 01:43 | 60 | 60 |

On combining both tables to create Table 3, I'd like to achieve the following:

**Table 3** - overall result:

| periodFrom | periodTo | timeFrom | timeTo | levelFrom | levelTo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 00:00 | 00:15 | 50 | 50 |
| 1 | 1 | 00:15 | 00:30 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 00:30 | 01:00 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 3 | 01:00 | 01:15 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 3 | 01:15 | 01:30 |  | 50 |
| 4 | 4 | 01:30 | 01:32 | 50 | 60 |
| 4 | 4 | 01:32 | 01:43 | 60 | 60 |
| 4 | 4 | 01:43 | 02:00 | 50 | 50 |

The entries of table 2 are combined with table 1 in such a way that `levelFrom` and `levelTo` in table 2 take precedence over those same values in table 1. I know I can do something like `SELECT COALESCE` on a `JOIN` but I'm unsure about how to handle the sequencing of the From and To variables. Any help much appreciated!

Comment: This seems, table2  data has more priority then table1 data.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I will update the question to make it clearer.